# Entity Framework : better way to do many to many query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, linq

Environment: EF6 code first

I have two tables e.g `user` and `activity` which have a many-to-many relation.

I want to know whether any user's activity has a given key, using Entity Framework in an asp.net mvc application.

1. is the following query performance wise?
2. is there any other way to write this query?

Query:

```
var userEntity = _dbcontext.Users.Find(userId);

var isAvailable = _dbcontext.Entry(userEntity)
                            .Collection(e => e.Activities)
                            .Query().Any(e => e.Name== "givenname");
```

**updated:**

i ran those queries and here are the time to run:

**1**

```
var userEntity = _dbcontext.Users.Find(userId);

var isAvailable = userEntity.Activities.Any(a => a.Name == "givenname");
```

**time:    5.39s** + time to fetch user

**2**

```
var isAvailable =_dbcontext.Users.Include(e => e.Activities)
                             .Any( u => u.UserId == userId 
                                    &&  u.Activities.Any(a => a.Name == "givenname")
                                 );
```

**time:     5.73s**

**3**

```
var userEntity = _dbcontext.Users.Find(userId);

var isAvailable = _dbcontext.Entry(userEntity)
                        .Collection(e => e.Activities)
                        .Query().Any(e => e.Name== "givenname");
```

**time:     5.95s**  + time to fetch user

so it seems that choosing the second form of query be reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
var isAvailable =_dbcontext.Users.Include(e => e.Activities)
                                 .Any( u => u.UserId == userId 
                                        &&  u.Activities.Any(a => a.Name == "givenname")
                                     );
```

If you haven't disabled lazy loading, then you don't need to call the `Include` extension method.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify this to:

```
var userEntity = _dbcontext.Users.Find(userId);

var isAvailable = userEntity.Activities.Any(a => a.Name == "givenname");
```

or maybe (I'm not quite clear what you're trying to achieve, from your question) - this doesn't take the `userId` into account, it just searches for *any* users that has *any* activity with that `givenname`:

```
var isAvailable = _dbcontext.Users.Any(u => u.Activities.Any(a => a.Name == "givenname"));
```

Comment: no just one user which is current user and also is there any way without first getting the user?

Answer (score 0):

Single trip to the DB:

```
var result = _dbcontext.Users.Where( u => u.UserId == userId )
    .Select( u => new {
        User = u, // optional
        IsAvailable = u.Activities.Any( a => a.Name == "givenname" )
    } )
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: activity table has many relation to user so _dbcontext.Activities.Any( a => a.UserId ) it's not possible

Comment: ah, so just follow the second example, returning user object is optional